# Ionic Angular ion-select with for loop not working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm new to Ionic. I'm trying to use `ion-select` inside a `ion-modal` with for loop. But it doesn't show select options. It gives me output like this

[image]

This is my code

modal.component.html

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>Add New TV Series</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-content>
      <ng-form>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label position="stacked">TV Series Title</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Enter TV Series Title" required></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label position="stacked">Released Year</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="number" placeholder="Enter TV Series Released Year" required></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label position="stacked">Season Count</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="number" placeholder="Enter Season Count Of TV Series" required></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        
        <!-- Select component --------------------------------- -->
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>TV Series Status</ion-label>
          <ion-select placeholder="Select Status" [(ngModel)]="selectedStatus">
            <ion-select-option *ngFor="let status of tvSeriesStatusList" [value]="status">
              {{status | titlecase}}
            </ion-select-option>
          </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
        <!-- Select component --------------------------------- -->

        <ion-row style="margin-top: 50px;">
          <ion-col>
            <ion-button type="submit" color="primary" expand="block">Add</ion-button>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col>
            <ion-button color="danger" expand="block">Cancel</ion-button>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>

      </ng-form>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

modal.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tv-modal-from',
  templateUrl: './tv-modal-from.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tv-modal-from.component.scss'],
})
export class TvModalFromComponent implements OnInit {

  tvSeriesStatusList: Array<string> = ['ENDED', 'RETURNING', 'CANCELED', 'MINI SERIES'];
  selectedStatus: string;
  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: could you please share which version of ionic-angular you are using

Comment: @Darpan I'm using Ionic Framework 5.8.5

Comment: I copied your code and got no problem for the display. But the ng-form tag seems not appropriate. Check : https://www.positronx.io/ionic-form-validation-tutorial/

Comment: try to remove `titlecase` and check